# sorting array and limiting output

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have a value type array $data, the print_r output is this

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [6] => Array (
            [ID] => 241
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [2084] => Array (
            [ID] => 240
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [2084] => Array (
            [ID] => 239
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [1936] => Array (
            [ID] => 237
        )
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [4162] => Array (
            [ID] => 236
        )
    ) 
)
```

Can i somehow sort the array by the second level array key for example [6],[2084] from lowest to highest, and the array is longer then i posted here but am i able to show only first two values after sorting, thank you in advance.

i tryed something like this

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    //echo "$key = $val\n";
    krsort($val);
    foreach ($val as $key1 => $val1) {
        echo  $val1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 0):

array_slice method can retrieve only n elements from array look at: 
http://php.net//manual/en/function.array-slice.php

also for sorting watch these functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php